# Send specific key ASCII code to terminal

Tags: c#, terminal, key, ascii

I want to force on terminal "Tab" clicking from my C# code.
I'm able to send any STRING value to the Bash and get the output, but how can I send the specific key to bash?  I want to send "TAB". Can I type into terminal some specific string to have this kind of solution?

I've tried 
`$'\t'`, some  `echo` combinations etc, but I can't force terminal to, for example, list the files in current directories.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

`SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")` will trigger the event of Tab being pressed in whichever window which will be active at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -e to enable the use of special characters when calling 'echo'. So, for example:

```
echo -e "test \t\t test"
```

Besides -e with the echo command there is another way to send tab. See below (with echo -e as the first example):

```
$ echo -e '[\t]'
[       ]

$ printf '[%b]\n' '\t'  # %b interprets backslashes in the same way as -e and $''
[       ]
```

Comment: I don't need tabulation. I need to send "TAB" key to list for example files in directories or auto completion.